# Due to vs given

Tags: word-usage

Good morning!

May I use "due to" like "given", as in the following example? If not, is there any other word (except "given") I could use in order to replace it?

I like to visit new people, especially foreigners, due to the different cultural values and backgrounds they usually have.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, "due to" fits fine in your example, but there are lots of other alternatives.

In this context, "due to" means "because of", which easily slots into your sentence:

> I like to visit new people, especially foreigners **because of** the different cultural values and backgrounds they usually have.

With some modification to the structure of your sentence, you could probably use quite a number of these alternatives:

- as
- as a result of
- on account of
- being
- considering
- for the reason that
- in that
- in view of
- on the grounds that
- owing to

Comment: Thank you very much! But do you think that "due to" also works in this sentence?

Comment: @lae96 Yes, "due to" works fine.

Answer (score 2):

'*Due to*' is grammatically possible here, but it literally means 'because of', 'as a result of', 'owing to' and is most often used to explain an undesired result. If you need a single word, something like '**considering**' could replace your original word. You can also use longer phrases in that place, e. g. '**taking into account**' or something clearly positive like '*being interested in knowledge about*', '*looking forward to learning more about*', etc.

Comment: Disagree. "Due to" certainly can reference a positive aspect of something.  Also, "because of" works very well in this sentence, assuming he likes to visit foreigners *because* he seeks exposure to different cultural values, etc.